# Unity Serialport communication over bluetooth is not getting updated on real time

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, serial-port

I wrote a small script that reads data from the serial port. Then on windows Bluetooth, I created an incoming port (com8).  And I connected to Bluetooth from android using an app called Bluetooth terminal. The problem is when  I run the script on Unity it is not updating the data in real-time. For example, I sent strings like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc... one by one it only updates something like 1, 3, 4, 6, etc.
But on the other hand, when I checked the com port using Arduino serial, it is updating in real-time without any problem.
below is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 5.0f;
    public Text outText;
    
    SerialPort sp=new SerialPort("COM8",9600);
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        sp.Open();
        sp.ReadTimeout =1;
   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
         if(sp.IsOpen){
             
            try{
               
                print(sp.ReadLine().ToString());
                outText.text=sp.ReadLine().ToString();
            }catch(System.Exception){
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add 'Ardity' from the Asset Store to your Unity project. (FREE)
   (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/ardity-arduino-unity-communication-made-easy-123819)
2. Add SerialController.cs to your GameObject and open it.
3. Add Debug.Log(message); inside Update().
4. Run the game and send a signal from the Bluetooth device.
5. Check the log value.